# Upgraded dotnet core 2.1 - ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed

Tags: c#, linux, jwt, ubuntu-17.10, .net-core-2.1

We have a development environment running in 2.0 on both Windows and Linux without problems.

This uses `JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken()` from the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` library to generate tokens.

We've upgraded to 2.1 and this method is now working correctly on Windows, but fails on the Linux distro (Ubuntu 17.10).

Has anyone else experienced this or found problems with this library?

We're trying to debug internally, but would appreciate if anyone has experienced a similar problem.

Comment: This could be a possible starting point for you, mate. [This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39985103/9622872) has a message from the Microsoft team. Perhaps it's just incompatible at this time for your version of Ubuntu? Best email the Microsoft squad while you're waiting here for some more concise answers as opposed to suggestions. :)

Comment: Weirdly, this came into play only when .NET Core 2.1 came out (a week or so ago). 2.0 worked perfectly with both Windows and Linux. However, this is definitely a good starting point, as it might be the same behaviour. Thank you!